# Alternative of espresso for windows

Tags: windows, ide, editor, macrabbit-espresso

Espresso has live preview feature which shows live changes of code as we write code.

I am searching for same feature in a tool for Windows?

Dreamweaver has that one, but doesn't support JS. Is there any other web editor or IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I know of is the [IntelliJ platform](http://jetbrains.com) ([WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)/[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)) with the live edit plugin. It works in combination with a Chrome plugin.

You can watch a demonstration of live edit in action [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wCVwdvufTds)

Instructions for setting up the Chrome plugin are [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/How+to+install+Chrome+extension).

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: [LIVEditor](http://liveditor.com) - the product name contains the word **live**, in order to emphasize its feature to show **live html/css preview**, which is, alone with the integrated **Firebug-like html element inspector** for showing **applied css styles**, the most important nature of this code editor.

[image: live html code editor that shows applied css styles of the selected html element]